# dynamically creating div with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to Create div dynamically  with unique id.. base on id we need to get values form the database ..but here can get id but divTag.innerHTML= 
not getting id to execute my sql query 
please help me out
thanks in adnvce

```
.dynamicDiv {
width:200px;
height:100px;
border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
background-color:#e1e1e1;
font-size:11px;
font-family:verdana;
color:#000;
padding:5px;
}

.dynamicDiv{ float:left;}


</style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function createDiv($id)
{

        var id =$id;
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");
        var id =$id;
        divTag.id = "div1";
        divTag.setAttribute("align","center");
        divTag.style.margin = "100px auto";
        divTag.className ="dynamicDiv";
        divTag.innerHTML = "<?php $sql =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID='$id'");
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        print_r($res);  
        ?>";
        document.body.appendChild(divTag);
        }

</script>
</head>
<body style="float:left;">
<div  style="float:left;">
     <b>Click this button to create div element dynamically</b>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value=
"create div" onClick="createDiv('<?php echo rand(); ?>');" />
```

Comment: javascript is executed on client side whereas php on server side so not going to work.

Comment: You will need to use ajax to get the record.

Answer (score 4):

You can not bring data from server with sending call to server, You can use [**jquery ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to bring the data and pass the id to filter the data.