# create a div dynamically for every row in database table ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I'm designing a website for my FYP, i have an customerOrder page, and a viewOrders page,
customer places order in CustomerOrder page. in viewOrders i want to display the result of sql query, in dynamically created "div" and "labels" with CSS assigned to them for each row of table, in following SqlDataReader.tnx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string localCnnString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LGDB"].ToString();
        SqlConnection SqlCnn = new SqlConnection(localCnnString);

        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        SqlDataReader dReader;

        SqlCnn.Open();
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCnn;
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlCmd.CommandText = "myrpoc";

        dReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dReader.Read())
        {
            //dynamic controls

        }

        dReader.Close();
        SqlCnn.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamically creating div with dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493660/dynamically-creating-div-with-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 2):

This scenario can be solved in many different ways. The general approach though is some sort of data binding.
If you're doing web forms I would look into the Repeater control, which will offer good template based data binding.

A less elegant way is to just loop out some dynamic html.

Answer (score 0):

you can use data binding approach for Repeater or Gridview or Datalist.

another way is by string building for dynamic html and using it in divContent.InnerHtml

**HTML**

```
<div id="divContent" runat="server">

</div>
```